# Converting the result of a TYPO3 repository query into a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, typo3

Is there a way to convert the result of a "findAll()" on a Repository into a JSON object, change the properties of specific records in Javascript and then return it to the Action and convert it back to be accessed by the Action for persisting it in the DB?

Basically this:

```
    $test= $this->testRepository->findAll();
    $testJSON = json_encode($test);
    $this->view->assign('testjson', $testJSON);
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`$test->toArray()`

The collection object (IIRC ObjectStorage) gives you the possibility to use the `toArray()` method and then encode that

Comment: I tried that already, a var_dump() gives me that as a result: string(4) "[{}]"...